# Keras: Unravel model for plotting / summary

Tags: python, plot, keras, neural-network

When I create a model in Keras like this:

```
from keras.models import Model

my_model = model_building_function() # returns a Keras Model
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
outputs = my_model(inputs)
my_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

the summary of `my_model` (using `Model.summary()`) would result in something like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input (InputLayer)            (None, None, None, 3)  0                                                                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 multiple             23561152    input[0][0]                                                                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,561,152
Trainable params: 23,454,912
Non-trainable params: 106,240
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Same thing holds for the plotted graph of `my_model` (`keras.utils.plot_model`).

Is there any way to unravel the model, so that the individual layers are visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `layers` attribute of a model/layer and print its summary if it's a model.

```
def sub_models(layer):

    if isinstance(layer, Model):
        print('summary for model ' + layer.name)
        layer.summary()

    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
        for l in layer.layers:
            sub_models(l)

sub_models(my_model)
```

Comment: I would like to have it as one plot/summary